# How to create divisional sites with roll up content in Sharepoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Need to prepare divisional sites with rollup content which are document libraries, calendar events and lists so that they appear on the root site.

Also can we have separate site collections for different departments and still be able to roll up content onto root site on Sharepoint 2013 foundation?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "rollup content", do you want all the content replicated to your root site?  Doesn't sound like a good idea if so.  If you just want navigation from the root site you can use Treeview by going into Site Settings, Treeview (under Look & Feel) and enable it there per site.  I don't think you can easily navigate between site collections though, rather use top level sites and then sub-sites

Comment: Documents which are shared on sub sites / team sites needs to appear on the root site, same for calendar events. They need not be duplicated though the documents / events which are shared needs to be available on the parent site
Also would like to know whether this feature is available for SharePoint 2013 foundation

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to achieve this and I don't believe SharePoint's architecture caters for this sort of thing.  Items are kept in one location and then users have to navigate to the correct location to find what they're looking for. But have a look at Tree View, it's the closest thing to seeing deep structures in one view, the best I can suggest